# Concatenating elements to the slot of an S4 class in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, r-s4

Consider the following three Rcpp functions:

```
void f(Rcpp::S4 A) {
  Rcpp::NumericVector x = A.slot("x");
  x[0] = 42;
}

void g(Rcpp::S4 A) {
  Rcpp::NumericVector x = A.slot("x");
  x.push_back(42);
}

void h(Rcpp::S4 A) {
  Rcpp::NumericVector x = A.slot("x");
  x.push_back(42);
  A.slot("x") = x;
}
```

Then, applying these functions to an instance of an S4 class, I obtain:

```
> setClass(Class = "VectorClass", slots = list(x = "numeric"))
> A <- new("VectorClass", x = c(0))
> f(A)
> A
An object of class "VectorClass"
Slot "x":
[1] 42

> A <- new("VectorClass", x = c(0))
> g(A)
> A
An object of class "VectorClass"
Slot "x":
[1] 0

> A <- new("VectorClass", x = c(0))
> h(A)
> A
An object of class "VectorClass"
Slot "x":
[1]  0 42
```

**My questions are**:

- Is the behaviour of function `g` correct? Given the way `f` works, I would have expected `g` to modify the slot `x` of `A`.
- I'm assuming that `h` is making a copy of `x`, probably when resizing the vector in the call to `push_back`. Is this copy avoidable? Is there a better way to do things than `h`?

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting example.  We generally recommend against `push_back` etc as the underlying `SEXP` will need a full copy on insertion.  And I giess for `g` the temp object created is the not the one in the slot, hence the difference to `h`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, Thanks for the quick reply, and for your constant assistance with all questions related to Rcpp. I will try to avoid using ```push_back```, since indeed I am starting to realise that it needs to make a copy.